# pandas: find partial string and use it in new columns

Tags: python, loops, pandas, vectorization

I would like to create a new columns in case a certain string is a substring of another columns. Suppose I have a DataFrame with one column df['A']:

```
         A           
0    bbh AA chd     
1    d10 DKL BB
2    kj AAdbl 5
3    kBB d7d dl
```

and a list:

```
check = ['AA', 'BB']
```

now I want to create column df['B'] that takes over the values from the list if they are found in df['A‘]:

```
      A             B
0    bbh AA chd     AA
1    d10 DKL BB     BB
2    kj AAdbl 5     AA
3    kBB d7d dl     BB
```

How can I accomplish this task while looping through the list (which in reality gets bigger than just two items) or by applying a function?

Comment: The preferred way to do this in pandas is `df['A'].str.extract('(%s)' % '|'.join(check), expand=False)`. The regex capture group `(AA|BB)` is used to extract the values here. Also look into `extractall` and `findall` if you want to find multiple strings in the same cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [iterrows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to iterate through the rows and check if the rows contains any elements inside the check list and then put it into a new column.

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for c in check:
        if c in row['A']:
            df.ix[idx, 'B'] = c
```

Output:

```
df
Out[16]: 
            A   B
0  bbh AA chd  AA
1  d10 DKL BB  BB
2  kj AAdbl 5  AA
3  kBB d7d dl  BB
```

Just one little confusion: what if the df contains both `AA` and `BB`? In this case, my code might needs to be modified a bit based on how you would like to define the output behavior.

Comment: thank you, @Qu Dong. It's working as intended. I just get this message (although I think I can discard that): 'SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead '.

Comment: While this works, using `iterrows` should really be considered a last resort in pandas since it is *very* slow. It is much better to stick with vectorised string methods such as [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for these kinds of tasks when possible.

Comment: appreciated @ajcr, works and vectorization is even preferred. still need to get a better understanding on that syntax though.

Answer (score 2):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

text = """A
bbh AA chd
d10 DKL BB
kj AAdbl 5
kBB d7d dl"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))

check = ['AA', 'BB']

print df

            A
0  bbh AA chd
1  d10 DKL BB
2  kj AAdbl 5
3  kBB d7d dl
```

#### Solution

```
df_expanded = df.A.str.split(expand=True)

checked = pd.concat(
    [df_expanded.apply(lambda s: s.str.rfind(chk)) for chk in check],
    keys=check
)

where = (checked >= 0).any(axis=1).unstack(0)
where = where.mul(where.columns.to_series(), axis=1)

final = pd.Series()
where.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
for c in where.columns:
    final = final.combine_first(where.loc[:, c])

df['B'] = final

print df

            A   B
0  bbh AA chd  AA
1  d10 DKL BB  BB
2  kj AAdbl 5  AA
3  kBB d7d dl  BB
```

Comment: thank you piRSquared but your solution delivers 'None' in index 2 and 3 whereas the AA and BB combination should be found as a substring.

Comment: @AI_Iskander fixed